# Best way to load modules in CodeIgniter MVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, module

I am new to the CodeIgniter fw of PHP and generally have medium experience with MVC. I am working on a project where using modules will make my life a lot easier.

There is something regarding the way you call the modules that is a bit unclear in my head. The solution I had was to call the full module in the controller and pass the code as a variable in the view and then just echo it. Here is a sample of that logic

```
// Controller
$var['login'] = // code that calls the module
$this->load->view('index', $var);

// View
<div class='navbar'> 
    <?= $login; ?>
</div>
```

However after a small search, I found this solution [Creating Block/Modules in Code Igniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596014/creating-block-modules-in-code-igniter)
(String path of the module (view2) in the controller, pass it to view1 and then call it in the main view): .

Which of the 2 logics is the one that follows the MVC standards in a better way?

**UPDATE**: I have found the answer on how to do both here: [how to load view into another view codeigniter 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402924/how-to-load-view-into-another-view-codeigniter-2-1)
but my question remains the same. Which is the best logic that follows the MVC standards better?

Comment: Did you try HMVC? https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: It is unclear what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

first create model object 
like
$model = new mymodel

where u want to call do this
 $this->model->your_function_name($parameter);

Comment: Why to involve models in that?